# The effect of atmospheric pressure on bodies on earth

Tags: newtonian-gravity, thought-experiment

My teacher asked in classroom what would happen if there were no gravity. This question motivated me to think of some other "What if" kind of situations.

I thought about what would happen if there were no atmospheric pressure, since our bodies now tolerating a high pressure of 1 atm. My thinking is that in absence of atmospheric pressure everything will start expanding, even the human body.

I want opinions of genius minds and I shall be highly obliged to have your's.

Comment: I am a genius, at least I think I am :), unfortunately nobody else thinks I am. Your question is pretty much answered  here http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3076/ and here, https://www.cnet.com/uk/news/what-happens-to-the-unprotected-human-body-in-space/   although it would not be as cold as in space.

Comment: Sorry @countTo but i m not i a genius, the language of question you have referred is going above my head.

Comment: hope you are not gonna mark it as duplicate because i don't see any similarity b/w my question and the question you have suggested.

Comment: Simply, but not in the point of view of physics, no atmosphere, no existence of bodies as well!

Comment: i can't get you,can you explain through an answer.

Comment: I think @Kosala just means, if there was **never** any atmosphere in the first place, we would not be here, that's all. It's not the same as your question.

Comment: @CountTo10, yep. That doesn't answer the question. Its just a little thought :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is breathe out. You wouldn't lose consciousness straight away; it might take up to 15 seconds as your body uses up the remaining oxygen from your bloodstream, and you could perhaps live for as long as two minutes without permanent injury.

If you **do** hold your breath, then, although you will not explode, the pressure inside your lungs will be greater than the complete lack of pressure outside, as there is no air to create pressure.  The air inside your lungs will expand,  burst your lungs and release air into the circulatory system.

After about 10 seconds or so, your skin  will begin to swell as the water in your body starts to turn to gas as there is no outside pressure. But human skin is strong enough to keep you from bursting; and, if the air suddenly returned to Earth, you would be ok

The moisture on your tongue may begin to boil, because water boils at lower temperatures as the air pressure reduces.